# Want Result from one to many relation table by Group By

Tags: sql-server

I would like to get result by "group by" but not luck. I can see other option but looking best perfomance query.

Thanks in Advance !

```
CREATE TABLE #Invoice (InvoiceId int, InvoiceDate datetime, NetAmount 
decimal(18,2))

CREATE TABLE #Payment (PaymentId int, InvoiceId int, PaidAmount 
decimal(18,2))

INSERT INTO #Invoice VALUES (101, '20180212', 5000)
INSERT INTO #Invoice VALUES (102, '20180112', 600)
INSERT INTO #Invoice VALUES (103, '20181211', 1800)
INSERT INTO #Invoice VALUES (104, '20180101', 1000)
INSERT INTO #Invoice VALUES (105, '20180212', 7000)

INSERT INTO #Payment VALUES (101,103,1800)
INSERT INTO #Payment VALUES (102,102,500)
INSERT INTO #Payment VALUES (103,101,2000)
INSERT INTO #Payment VALUES (103,101,3000)
```

Create this query :

```
SELECT 
INV.InvoiceDate,
SUM(Inv.NetAmount) as NetAmount,
SUM(ISNULL(PY.PaidAmount,0)) As PaidAmount
From #Invoice INV
LEFT JOIN #Payment PY
ON PY.InvoiceId = INV.InvoiceId
GROUP BY
INV.InvoiceDate
```

Get Result :

```
InvoiceDate NetAmount   PaidAmount
2018-01-01  1000.00     0.00
2018-01-12  600.00      500.00
```

> 2018-02-12 17000.00 5000.00 ****Issue: Net values should be 12000 not 17000

```
2018-12-11  1800.00     1800.00
```

Expected Result :

```
InvoiceDate NetAmount   PaidAmount
2018-01-01  1000.00     0.00
2018-01-12  600.00      500.00
2018-02-12  5000.00     5000.00
2018-12-11  1800.00     1800.00
```

Comment: Try to avoid ambiguos date formats like `dd/MM/yyyy`/`MM/dd/YYYY` when supplying sample data; especially when all your sample data is valid for both formats. I couldn't work out at all our you were getting your results until i realised that it was the latter format.

Comment: Following your logic, should `NetAmount` for `20180212` not be `12000`? If not, why is the `NetAmount` value from Invoice 105 ignored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ***assumes*** that the expected results the OP has provided is *wrong*. They have the value `5000` for the `NetAmount` on `20180212`, however there are 2 invoices on that date with the values `5000` and `7000`, making `12000`. If `5000` is correct, we need details on why the value of invoice `105` (`7000`) is not to be included.

Anyway, on the assumption the expected results is wrong, this gets the result I believe you are looking for:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT I.InvoiceId,
           I.InvoiceDate,
           I.NetAmount,
           P.PaymentId,
           P.PaidAmount,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY I.InvoiceId, I.InvoiceDate ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN
    FROM #Invoice I
         LEFT JOIN #Payment P ON I.InvoiceId = P.InvoiceId)
SELECT C.InvoiceDate,
       SUM(CASE RN WHEN 1 THEN C.NetAmount END) AS NetAmount,
       ISNULL(SUM(C.PaidAmount),0) AS PaidAmount
FROM CTE C
GROUP BY C.InvoiceDate;
```

Comment: So did this answer the question, @AGH? Are the expected results wrong?

Comment: Yes I got my expected result and I’m really grateful for your help but will this give me performance ?

Comment: Why do you believe it would perform poorly, @AGH?

Comment: Bcz you are pulling data into CTE and then doing grouping operation, so during pulling data will take time as i have huge data. I just provide you sample data for easy to use.

Comment: A CTE is an **expression**, not an object. I'm not pulling data "into it" as a CTE doesn't hold data. A CTE is far more similar to something like a `CASE` (expression), where as it seems you think it operates more like a Table Variable, or Temporary Table. For something like the above the most expensive thing is likely going to be `ROW_NUMBER`. Not the `CTE`, and not the (conditional) `SUM`. How much cost that'll be depends on your indexing though.